# riak: stumped on a basho MapReduce challenge

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, riak

Working through their MapReduce tutorial, and Basho posits a MR challenge [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/advanced/mapreduce/#Bigger-Data-Examples), given daily stock data for the `GOOG` ticker:

> Find the largest day for each month in terms of dollars traded, and
>   subsequently the largest overall day. *Hint*: You will need at least
>   one each of map and reduce phases.

Each day in the `goog` bucket has a key that corresponds to its data and corresponding data that looks like this:

```
"2010-04-21":{
Date: "2010-04-21",
Open: "556.46",
High: "560.25",
Low: "552.16",
Close: "554.30",
Volume: "2391500",
Adj Close: "554.30"
}
```

Due to my relative lack of familiarity with the MR paradigm (and, candidly, Javascript), I wanted to work through how to do this. I assume that most of the work here would actually get done in the `reduce` function, and that you'd want a `map` function that looks something like:

```
function(value, keyData, arg){
  var data = Riak.mapValuesJson(value)[0];  
  var obj = {};
  obj[data.Date] = Math.abs(data.Open - data.Close);
  return [ obj ];
}
```

which would give you a list, by day, if not of dollars traded per day, at least the change in the stock price by day.

The question I would then have would be how to structure a `reduce` function that is able to parse through by month, select for only the largest value per month, and then sort everything from largest month to smallest.

Am I shortchanging the work that I need to do in my `map` function here, or is this roughly the right idea?

Answer (score 0):

I originally authored that challenge! Unless you'd like me to just give you the answer, I'll give you this hint: the key here is to think in terms of aggregate functions. How do you need to group the entries to find the maximum for each month, and then the maximum across the entire dataset?

Also, from the given data you can't know the exact amount of money exchanged in the day, but you could make a guess by multiplying the average price by the volume of shares traded.